# Python - doing math with built-ins vs math module

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

If x is a number. In python `x**(1/2.0)` [or even `x**(0.5)`] and `sqrt(x)` do the exact same thing. Both methods will return the square root of a given number. for `sqrt` to work though we have to import the math module (`form math import sqrt`). Is there any reason to use one over the other method? I wonder: becuase `sqrt()` has to be imported could it also be faster?

Comment: You can easily test the speed with the [```timeit``` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)

Comment: ... there may be subtle differences ... if all you need is sqrt i would just use `sqrt = lambda x:x**0.5` ... but if you need other stuff from math use the math library ... early optimization is a cardinal sin in python

Comment: `x ** (1/2)` will *not* do what you expect in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If calculating square root of a constant integer, the `**` operator maybe several times faster than `sqrt`, but when using a variable instead, `sqrt` is faster than both `**` and `math.sqrt`:

```
In [38]: %timeit -n1000000 3**.5
1000000 loops, best of 3: 46.7 ns per loop

In [39]: %timeit -n1000000 sqrt(3)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 312 ns per loop

In [40]: %timeit -n1000000 math.sqrt(3)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 377 ns per loop

In [41]: x=3

In [42]: %timeit -n1000000 x**.5
1000000 loops, best of 3: 469 ns per loop

In [43]: %timeit -n1000000 sqrt(x)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 327 ns per loop

In [44]: %timeit -n1000000 math.sqrt(x)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 430 ns per loop
```

Comment: I was just about to do this :P

Comment: you do a different number of loops for each. not that it matters really. It would be nice that both test cases were equal

Comment: Unfair comparison. The method lookup is killing you. When you do `from math import sqrt` and then call `sqrt(x)`, it's a lot faster than `**`.

Comment: To be fair, using a variable instead of an int constant in both makes them closer; `3**.5` can be optimized away and only runs once.

Comment: @Wooble I would be surprised to learn that Python attempted that optimization. From what I understand, python attempts no optimizations whatsoever because even basic operators can change. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: @zhangxaochen your two results contradict each other

Comment: @TimPietzcker I dont see it's a lot faster using 'sqrt' than 'math.sqrt', maybe just 20% percent faster?

Comment: In my tests it was over 50 % faster (cPython 2.7.6 on Win7 x64).

Comment: @TimPietzcker so sqrt is faster it seems. Maybe update the answer to say .sqrt() is faster?

Answer (score 1):

If you ever want to look directly at the python bytecode to dive deeper into these differences I would suggest the `dis` module. Here's an example showing exactly *why* the math version is different.

```
>>> import math
>>> import dis
>>>
>>> def builtin(number):
...     return number ** 0.5
... 
>>> def with_math(number):
...     return math.sqrt(number)
... 
>>> dis.dis(builtin)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (number)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0.5)
              6 BINARY_POWER        
              7 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(with_math)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (math)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (sqrt)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (number)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

The first two commands in the `with_math` option should probably be ignored since they won't have to happen every time this is called in reality. But then you can see that the two functions are in fact extremely similar. The main difference being that the math version replaces the `LOAD_CONST` and `BINARY_POWER` with a single `CALL_FUNCTION`. While the lookup is going to make this slower starting out, the `math` version is going to be faster in the long run, since you can largely ignore the first 6 cycles.

Comment: It's not slower; you're doing an attribute lookup that the OP doesn't do.

Comment: @Wooble you're totally right, looked at the output again and updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends what you want to do

For a simple expression, the operator might overshoot `math.sqrt`, but if you need to use as a callback, using `math.sqrt` would perform better compared to rolling out a lambda for using the operator

```
In [4]: %timeit math.sqrt(3)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 148 ns per loop

In [5]: %timeit 3**.5
100000000 loops, best of 3: 19.5 ns per loop

In [12]: %timeit -n 1000 map(lambda e: e**.5, range(1,100))
1000 loops, best of 3: 31.3 us per loop

In [13]: %timeit -n 1000 map(math.sqrt, range(1,100))
1000 loops, best of 3: 14.6 us per loop
```

Comment: I did not upvoted you answer. Can you please tell me why you are doing a different numbers of loops for each?

Comment: @JebediahKerman: timeit is magic and picks the number of loops itself.

Comment: @Wooble I think the results would be more meaningful if the number of loops was equal for each method

Comment: @JebediahKerman: unless timeit is somehow broken, it shouldn't matter. The algorithm it uses to determine how many loops to run is designed to make the results come out right. feel free to force it to run more to confirm you get the same results, though.

Comment: @JebediahKerman: I don;t think so that matters. timeit returns an average so, it has some heuristic thoughts while performing the calculation.

Comment: @Wooble: If all that matters, I have updated the result